# RequestAnimationFrame call time changes depending on my canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

On my application, I have a canvas which CSS size (CSS, not html) updates depending on the window size.

I have a main gameplayLoop which looks like this :

```
run = function(){

    console.log(timerDiff(frameTime));

    game.inputManage();
    game.logics();
    game.graphics.animate();
    game.graphics.render();

    frameTime = timerInit();

    requestAnimFrame(run);

}
```

My requestAnimFrame function is the one from Paul Irish :

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

So basically the problem is that the timer that I log which measures the time between the requestAnimFrame call and the effective function call totally changes.
If my browser is in fullscreen I get like 50/60 ms, and if I have a small window I can get to something like 10 ms.

As the requestAnimFrame call is supposed to call constantly the function under a 60fps rythm (which is something like 30 ms I think) I shouldn't have this kind of result, since there is basically nothing happening between the timer's creation and its check, except the requestAnimFrame

I also have some recurring micro-freezes (less than a second) which happens like every 2/3 seconds. But the timer doesn't detect any change in the time (like even the time counter of javascript is blocked)

My timers functions are like this but it doesn't really matter here

```
timerInit = function()
{
    return new Date();
}

timerDiff = function(datePrev)
{
    return new Date().getTime() - datePrev.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Your entire approach is flawed, `requestAnimationFrame` does not have a pre-cooked framerate, it will "request" the next "animation frame" as soon as it is called.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is locked to the vertical sync in Chrome by default. I *think* that is the case in Firefox too. So in most situations, `requestAnimationFrame` results in 60fps (assuming your code can keep up, of course).

Comment: Good question. My game also "freezes" about every 3 seconds and I am also using `requestAnimationFrame`. I naively thought it was the garbage collector, even though I allocate basically no objects.

Comment: Well anyway I have the exact same thing with a setTimeout which is totally strange. How can a setTimeout's time vary depending on a window's size ?

Comment: `setTimeout`, like `requestAnimationFrame`, does the best that it can with no guarantees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the standard basically says that `requestAnimationFrame` will "do its best" to run at a "consistent" frame rate. That doesn't guarantee a 60fps; it just states that it will animate as fast as it can.

My experience with it has been as dim as yours so far unfortunately. I ended up going back to `setTimeout`. It goes at about the same rate, and graphical updates are accurate and don't skip a beat as they did with `requestAnimationFrame`. Sure it wasn't 60fps, but at least you could tell what was going on.

I'm sure the performance will only improve as browser developers optimize the new function, but for the time being, consider going back to `timeouts`.

Edit: I would like to remind people that this was answered a year ago, and the times have changed :)

Comment: Well I tried that. It seems to help on firefox and IE but not on chrome.


As a result : the delta (the time that my function lasts) is always something like 10 ms, but if I measure the time between the setTimeout and the effective function debut, I have something randomly between 5 and 60 ms depending on the screen size.

I really don't understand how a canvas size can change a setTimeout call time...

Comment: @Malharhak My best guess it that the browser thinks it will need to redraw more pixels. Also, a `timeout` period of 33 (or 30fps) seems to  work fine for me. 1000/60 is about 16 milliseconds, which is pretty fast.

Comment: So I tried something on my render mode : If my canvas is in dynamic resolution (its pixel width and height changes with the window) it works nice. But when it's in "css" mode, my canvas which has a resolution of 800*600 but is css-resized makes my game laggy as described above.

Pretty strange

Comment: From my experience requestAnimationFrame will run up to 60 FPS if your draw loop is fast enough and consistently the same speed.  I've seen it run faster than 60fps when you are doing something slow in your callback function and then it speeds up.  If you know when this is you can call cancelAnimationFrame and then requestAnimationFrame again to bring it back to 60 fps or less.

Comment: Setting timeout to anything below 45 will result in random result, most likely you'll get a 45 ms, even when you asked for 16. So this solution is excluded : drive requestAnimationFrame with a setInterval. And do only the draw, not the update, within the ReqAF. I would bet your draw time was above 16, and that's why going to a setTimeout,hence to a 45 ms frame time, helped the game to have a consistent framerate.

Comment: Sorry, but requestAnimationFrame doesn't work like setTimeout; there's an example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

*"So basically the problem is that the timer that I log which measures the time between the requestAnimFrame call and the effective function call totally changes..."*

Of course it does, that's why you need to measure it and BASED ON THIS TIME DIFFERENCE VALUE you calculate your next frame.

Let's assume you want to animate the 'left' css property of a div from 0px to 120px in 1 second with 60 fps.

- **using setTimeout**, because YOU set the number of frames, you know how much you must  increment the 'left' property: 120px/60frames = 2px/frame
- **using requestAnimationFrame**, you have no ideea when the next frame will happen, until it happens; then you measure the time difference between this and the previous frame an you calculate  the value you must increment the css 'left value' with; if the frame happens after 500ms, increment distance = (120px * 500ms)/1000ms = 60px; the ideea is that at the start of the animation you can't have a fixed, predetermined value to increment with at each frame, you need to calculate it dynamically based on the time difference

So even if the animation won't be at the advertised 60fps, if frames are skipped, every frame that is not skipped will draw the accurate updated situation.

You have to fiddle a bit to decide when the animation should end.